# Determining which R packages, and dependencies, use DLL files

Tags: r

I work in a corporate environment that uses Microsoft Windows Defender Application Control (WDAC) to provide security. This blocks unsigned EXE and DLL files from being installed on devices. R packages which use DLLs fail to install. The workaround to this is provide an R installation from an approved central source which also copies over a default set of packages, such as tidyverse, data.table etc. to the R library. Users can continue to install additional packages which are built with native R, but run into issues if they try to install, build from source, or update packages with DLL files in.

Is there a way to check whether a package uses DLL files in advance of installation?

Output something like:-

```
check_dll(foo)
result: "This package and its dependencies have no DLL files. You can install this package"

check_dll(bar)
result: "bar does not have any DLL files, but one dependency, OOF, uses DLL files. 
You have already have a version of OOF installed so it should be safe to install bar"

check_dll(foobar)
result: "foobar has a DLL. Do not attempt to install foobar".

check_dll(RABOOF)
result: "RABOOF does not have any DLL files, but one of it's dependencies, 
foobar, does have a DLL file. Do not attempt to install RABOOF".
```

`tools::package_dependencies()` will list the package dependencies, but nothing else.

Downloading the zip file from CRAN and inspecting it for a libs/x64 folder with contents will work, but seems a heavyweight approach. Theoretically if a package has lots of dependencies this could result in downloading a lot of files unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the `NeedsCompilation` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file.  If it is `"yes"`, there will be a DLL.  If it is `"no"`, there probably won't be.  (If it is not there, the package wasn't built properly, so all bets are off.)

The test is not perfect, because packages can put DLLs into the `inst` folder to get them installed without compiling them, though CRAN isn't supposed to allow that:  "Source packages may not contain any form of binary executable code."  But packages like `pak` (mentioned in the comments) may be allowed to get around this rule, e.g. by downloading binaries, so the test isn't perfect.  You will also need to put together a blacklist of packages that will fail your WDAC tests even though they claim not to need compilation, containing `pak` and others like it.

The `NeedsCompilation` field is included as a column of the result of `available.packages()`, so it is very easy to access without trying to install the package.

Comment: This is a good answer but there’s at least one exception: ‘pak’ has `NeedsCompilation: no`, has zero dependencies, but nevertheless ships with embedded DLLs. It gets around the CRAN limitation by sneakily installing and embedding its development package dependencies (including some that require compilation) at build time on CRAN.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  I've expanded my answer to discuss this issue.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. The need to contain a list of non-compliant packages within my function is non-ideal, but with a current length of 1 is easy to maintain at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted the answer from user2554330 as the best solution. It makes use of the normal set of commands used for package management; and the matrix generated by `available.packages()` can be passed to `tools::package_dependencies()`, removing the need for multiple internet queries.

For completeness I am documenting another possible solution. A script could query the unofficial CRAN Github mirror https://docs.r-hub.io/#cranatgh and look for a /src directory in each package project.